# Elimination of tertiary alkyl halide with lithium aluminium hydride to give alkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides

I'm confused about the mechanism and thus cannot decide which alkene would be the product. Reaction with primary and secondary alkyl halides gives alkanes. What about this case?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE. If you have questions about the site you can always visit the [help]. Your question appears to be of the homework type that falls under the guidelines described [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/142#142). The bottom line is that in order to get guidance on this type of problem, you must show all the work and effort that you can towards solving it yourself first. For example, you could write out a mechanism and explain what the different products could be.

Comment: 3rd degree alkyl halides undergo elimination hence give alkenes as product unlike 2nd and 1st degree alkyl halides

Comment: Note that the correct wording is *primary*, *secondary*, and *tertiary*. The use of $1^\circ$, $2^\circ$, and $3^\circ$ is a shorthand for that - it is not a shorthand for "first-degree", "second-degree", or "third-degree".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reaction is E1 due to the formation of most stable tertiary carbocation, as such the double bond will be on the most substited side to give most substituted alkene as a major product.

Comment: It's clearly written in my comment that the reaction is E1

Comment: sorry. I wanted to confirm